# Tengo que actualizar un banner en mi sitio web todos los dias en un rango horario

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger, events

Estoy necesitando crear un evento en donde cada dia, se active y desactive un banner en los horarios entre las 19:30 hs y las 21:45 hs pero nose como hacerlo. Busque informacion y documentacion, pero no entiendo como crear esta clase de eventos en donde cada dia se genere el update de activacion o desactivacion del banner.

Paso a explicar la tabla en donde se encuentra este banner se llama "banners" y posee un campo llamado "name", y el valor del banner para ese campo es 'nocturno'. Tambien tiene un campo start y un campo expire, en donde se colocan las fechas de comienzo y finalizacion de este banner.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian ayudar a crear este evento o trigger para no tener q hacer este procedimiento de update todos los dias a mano.

Comment: ¿Y no sería más fácil añadir esa lógica en la página? mostrar ese html si cumple con una criterio específico, sea de horas o lo que sea. No necesitas hacer ningún update si la página no se carga entre esas horas.

Answer (score 0):

Crear un evento en mysql es tarea relativamente sencilla, solo deberías poner en el bloque `BEGIN` `END` la instrucción que ejecutas manualmente para activar o desactivar el banner, ahora lo que yo haría sería poner una variable de control en la base datos tipo boolean (1,0) la cual setear mediante un evento a 1 ó 0 activado o desactivado según correspondiese, pero para esto habría que modificar el código de tu página y leer dicho valor y en el caso de estar activo mostrar dicho banner.

[eventos en mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

```sql
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Saves total number of sessions then clears the table each day'
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO site_activity.totals (time, total)
          SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, COUNT(*)
            FROM site_activity.sessions;
        DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
      END |

delimiter ;
```